# Horizontal pgfplot (xbar) remove bar labels

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I want to create a horizontal barchart in latex. I already have the following but I want to remove the value labels at the end of the bars.

Can someone help we with this issue? Thanks in advance!

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Importance},
    symbolic y coords={LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE,REGIONUNKNOWN,MAXDM,TOTALGIFTS,FREQUENCYRESPONSE,LASTGIFTAMOUNT,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS,FREQUENCYTARGETED,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE,GENDERMALE,GENDERUNKNOWN,MONTH,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED,RESPONSERATIO,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE,GENDERFEMALE,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE,REGIONNORTH,REGIONWEST,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG,REGIONEAST,REGIONSOUTH,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD},
    ytick=data,
    xbar,
    bar width=3pt,
    xmin=0,
    enlarge y limits,
    height=16cm, width=9cm,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]

  \addplot coordinates {
    (6.94,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE)(9.52,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS)(12.46,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE)(14.77,REGIONUNKNOWN)(15.26,MAXDM)(16.35,TOTALGIFTS)(17.19,FREQUENCYRESPONSE)(17.72,LASTGIFTAMOUNT)(17.97,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT)(18.09,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE)(18.34,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE)(19.43,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS)(19.74,FREQUENCYTARGETED)(20.2,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE)(20.66,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE)(21.41,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT)(21.44,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE)(22.89,GENDERMALE)(23.88,GENDERUNKNOWN)(24.82,MONTH)(25.12,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW)(25.91,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE)(26.31,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED)(26.71,RESPONSERATIO)(30.65,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW)(31.66,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE)(32.61,GENDERFEMALE)(37.14,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE)(43.36,REGIONNORTH)(50.05,REGIONWEST)(51.16,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN)(53.3,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD)(53.67,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG)(58.62,REGIONEAST)(63.79,REGIONSOUTH)(72.32,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE)(77.05,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD)
  };
  \addplot coordinates {
    (0.07,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS)(0.13,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS)(0.15,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE)(0.81,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE)(1.99,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE)(2.14,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE)(2.74,REGIONUNKNOWN)(3.12,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE)(3.77,MAXDM)(4.79,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT)(7.97,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE)(7.97,TOTALGIFTS)(8.2,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE)(8.52,FREQUENCYRESPONSE)(8.65,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT)(10.98,FREQUENCYTARGETED)(11.04,GENDERUNKNOWN)(11.22,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW)(11.23,MONTH)(11.48,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE)(11.85,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE)(13.08,GENDERMALE)(13.25,LASTGIFTAMOUNT)(13.7,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED)(14.8,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW)(15.1,RESPONSERATIO)(15.22,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE)(17.01,GENDERFEMALE)(36.22,REGIONNORTH)(37.07,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN)(45.06,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD)(45.54,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG)(45.82,REGIONWEST)(50.67,REGIONEAST)(56.05,REGIONSOUTH)(62.73,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE)(65.16,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD)
  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: I understand, I kept the most imporant one

Comment: Thanks for updating your post! Asking them in separate questions will make it easier for future users with the same problem, to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are added by the `nodes near coords` key. Simply remove it if you don't want to have labels there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{font=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Importance},
    symbolic y coords={LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE,REGIONUNKNOWN,MAXDM,TOTALGIFTS,FREQUENCYRESPONSE,LASTGIFTAMOUNT,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS,FREQUENCYTARGETED,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE,GENDERMALE,GENDERUNKNOWN,MONTH,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED,RESPONSERATIO,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE,GENDERFEMALE,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE,REGIONNORTH,REGIONWEST,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG,REGIONEAST,REGIONSOUTH,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD},
    ytick=data,
    xbar,
    bar width=3pt,
    xmin=0,
    enlarge y limits,
    height=16cm, width=9cm,
%    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]

  \addplot coordinates {
    (6.94,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE)(9.52,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS)(12.46,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE)(14.77,REGIONUNKNOWN)(15.26,MAXDM)(16.35,TOTALGIFTS)(17.19,FREQUENCYRESPONSE)(17.72,LASTGIFTAMOUNT)(17.97,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT)(18.09,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE)(18.34,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE)(19.43,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS)(19.74,FREQUENCYTARGETED)(20.2,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE)(20.66,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE)(21.41,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT)(21.44,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE)(22.89,GENDERMALE)(23.88,GENDERUNKNOWN)(24.82,MONTH)(25.12,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW)(25.91,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE)(26.31,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED)(26.71,RESPONSERATIO)(30.65,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW)(31.66,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE)(32.61,GENDERFEMALE)(37.14,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE)(43.36,REGIONNORTH)(50.05,REGIONWEST)(51.16,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN)(53.3,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD)(53.67,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG)(58.62,REGIONEAST)(63.79,REGIONSOUTH)(72.32,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE)(77.05,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD)
  };
  \addplot coordinates {
    (0.07,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS)(0.13,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS)(0.15,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE)(0.81,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE)(1.99,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE)(2.14,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE)(2.74,REGIONUNKNOWN)(3.12,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE)(3.77,MAXDM)(4.79,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT)(7.97,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE)(7.97,TOTALGIFTS)(8.2,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE)(8.52,FREQUENCYRESPONSE)(8.65,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT)(10.98,FREQUENCYTARGETED)(11.04,GENDERUNKNOWN)(11.22,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW)(11.23,MONTH)(11.48,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE)(11.85,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE)(13.08,GENDERMALE)(13.25,LASTGIFTAMOUNT)(13.7,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED)(14.8,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW)(15.1,RESPONSERATIO)(15.22,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE)(17.01,GENDERFEMALE)(36.22,REGIONNORTH)(37.07,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN)(45.06,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD)(45.54,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG)(45.82,REGIONWEST)(50.67,REGIONEAST)(56.05,REGIONSOUTH)(62.73,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE)(65.16,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD)
  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My two cents to improve upon the accepted answer and adhere to good practices:

For readability, **delegate data to a table**.
For efficiency, **auto-assign labels** rather than typing manually.

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
value,key
6.94,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFTMANDATE
9.52,RECENCYTARGETEDDAYS
12.46,LASTRESPONSETYPEMANDATE
14.77,REGIONUNKNOWN
15.26,MAXDM
16.35,TOTALGIFTS
17.19,FREQUENCYRESPONSE
17.72,LASTGIFTAMOUNT
17.97,DAYSSINCEFIRSTGIFT
18.09,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEACTIVE
18.34,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKEX-MANDATE
19.43,RECENCYRESPONSEDAYS
19.74,FREQUENCYTARGETED
20.2,FIRSTGIFTSINGLE
20.66,YTDFREQUENCYRESPONSE
21.41,LASTRESPONSETYPESINGLEGIFT
21.44,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKNOMANDATE
22.89,GENDERMALE
23.88,GENDERUNKNOWN
24.82,MONTH
25.12,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVENEW
25.91,ACTIVEMANDATECHECKACTIVE
26.31,YTDFREQUENCYTARGETED
26.71,RESPONSERATIO
30.65,LASTRESPONSETYPENEW
31.66,LASTRESPONSETYPENORESPONSE
32.61,GENDERFEMALE
37.14,STATUSRESPONSEACTIVEINACTIVE
43.36,REGIONNORTH
50.05,REGIONWEST
51.16,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYUNKNOWN
53.3,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYVERYOLD
53.67,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYYOUNG
58.62,REGIONEAST
63.79,REGIONSOUTH
72.32,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYMIDDLE
77.05,BIRTHYEARCATEGORYOLD
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xmin = 0,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\mydata}{key},
    xlabel = {importances},
    bar width=3pt,
    height=14cm
]
\addplot table [y expr=\coordindex,x=value] {\mydata};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Gives

[image]

See the [full interactive example](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=zzvv1r).